# Batch normalization neural network using ADAM as optimizer

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, batch-normalization

I am trying to create a neural network using batch normalization and Adam as optimizer but during optimization, there is an error that says operand cannot be broadcast together. Can anyone tell me where is the error?

```py
def Adam(W,dW,lr,beta1=0.9,beta=0.999,epsilon=1e-7,k=0):
    m=np.zeros_like(W)
    v=np.zeros_like(W)
    k=k+1
    m=beta1*m+(1-beta1)*dW
    v=beta2*v+(1-beta2)*dW*dW
    hatm=m/(1-np.power(beta1,k))
    hatv=v/(1-np.power(beta2,k))
    return W-lr/np.maximum(np.sqrt(hatv),epsilon)*hatm

nx_train=x_train/255
nx_test=x_test/255

d0=nx_train.shape[1]
d1=200
d2=100
d3=10

np.random.seed(8)
W1=np.random.rand(d0,d1)*0.2-0.1
W2=np.random.rand(d1,d2)*0.2-0.1
W3=np.random.rand(d2,d3)*0.2-0.1
b1=np.zeros(d1)
b2=np.zeros(d2)
b3=np.zeros(d3)
gamma1=np.ones(d1)
beta1=np.zeros(d1)
gamma2=np.ones(d2)
beta2=np.zeros(d2)

lr=0.01
batch_size=100
epoch=100
shuffle=True

y_train=predict(nx_train,W1,b1,gamma1,beta1,W2,b2,gamma2,beta2,W3,b3)
y_test=predict(nx_test,W1,b1,gamma1,beta1,W2,b2,gamma2,beta2,W3,b3)

train_rate,train_err=accuracy_rate(y_train,t_train),cross_entropy_error(y_train,t_train)
test_rate,test_err=accuracy_rate(y_test,t_test),cross_entropy_error(y_test,t_test)
print("{0:3d} train_rate={1:6.2f}% test_rate={2:6.2f}% train_err={3:8.5f} test_err={4:8.5f}".format((0), train_rate*100, test_rate*100, train_err, test_err))


for i in range(epoch):
    for j in range(0,nx_train.shape[0],batch_size):
        W1,b1,gamma1,beta1,W2,b2,gamma2,beta2,W3,b3=learn(nx_train[j:j+batch_size],t_train[j:j+batch_size],W1,b1,gamma1,beta1,W2,b2,gamma2,beta2,W3,b3,lr)

    y_train=predict(nx_train,W1,b1,gamma1,beta1,W2,b2,gamma2,beta2,W3,b3)
    y_test=predict(nx_test,W1,b1,gamma1,beta1,W2,b2.gamma2,beta2,W3,b3)


    train_rate,train_err=accuracy_rate(y_train,t_train),cross_entropy_error(y_train,t_train)
    test_rate,test_err=accuracy_rate(y_test,t_test),cross_entropy_error(y_test,t_test)

    test_predictions = np.argmax(y_test,1)
    true_classes = np.argmax(t_test,1)
    cm=confusion_matrix(true_classes, test_predictions)
    print(cm)

    print("{0:3d} train_rate={1:6.2f}% test_rate={2:6.2f}% train_err={3:8.5f} test_err={4:8.5f}".format((i+1), train_rate*100, test_rate*100, train_err, test_err))
```

The error says "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (784,200) " at "v=beta2*v+(1-beta2)*dW*d".